# Cannot observe property [] of Object

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

I have a custom component that has an `items` property, defined as `@children` for the component:

```js
@children(`${ComponentConfiguration.prefix}tracker-item`) items = [];
```

`tracker-item` is a simple view-model with a `@noView` annotation, and has only one property.

The items are defined in my view like this:

```html
<tracker-item label="${trackerElementModel.steps[0] |   displayDate:'DD MMMM'}"> ${"PURCHASE.RQT_DTE" | t} </tracker-item>
```

This worked perfectly, but after I updated my project in order to build it with aurelia-cli, I see this error  every time the component is called:

```
WARN [property-observation] Cannot observe property 'items' of object 
TrackerComponent {_isAttached: false, _taskQueue: TaskQueue, _useTaskQueue: true, _alertService: AlertService, parentElement: null…}
```

TrackerComponent is the name of my custom component.

I don't understand where that error comes from, because somewhere else in my code I have the same definition for another custom component which don't raise the same error.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: What is the value of ComponentConfiguration.prefix here?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of the warning on my custom element.

Apparently, this only happens when you use @children annotation at a property level. If you move the annotation to a class level the warning should go away. In your case the class level annotation would look something like this:

```
@children(name: 'items', selector: `${ComponentConfiguration.prefix}tracker-item`)
export class <yourClass> {
     ...
}
```